# Entity Framework Search Function ASP.NET Webforms

Tags: asp.net, entity-framework, search, repeater

I have an SQL2014 database that contains clothing products.

The database is integrated in an ASP.NET webforms website using gridviews, formviews, repeaters and now the entity framework.

I wish to have a simple search function on the website where users can search for the partial name of a product and then the product name is displayed in a list (the database field is called 'Name')

I have a textbox control (txtWord), button (btnSearch) and repeater (rptrSearch) to display the results.

I have then added a method to the button which I believe should work to show the search results however I get nothing.

**C# Code**

```
protected void btnSearch_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        string searchWord = txtWord.Text;

        ZaraEntities db = new ZaraEntities();

        var results = db.Products.Where(p => p.Name == searchWord);

        rptrSearch.DataSource = results.ToList();
        rptrSearch.DataBind();

    }
```

**HTML**

```
<asp:TextBox ID="txtWord" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
<asp:Button ID="btnSearch" runat="server" Text="Button" />
<asp:Repeater ID="rptrSearch" runat="server">
    <HeaderTemplate>
        <div>
    </HeaderTemplate>

    <ItemTemplate>
        <div>
        </div>
    </ItemTemplate>

    <FooterTemplate>
        </div>
    </FooterTemplate>
</asp:Repeater>
```

Is there something wrong with the code and/or is it something to do with my repeater  being blank?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like you're attempting to match the data field exactly instead of the partial name ans you specified.
The following snippet shows how to get a partial field look-up using the Contains operator.

Try this:

```
var results = from p in db.Products
   where p.Name.Contains(searchWord)
   select p;
```

Comment: I figured it out this morning but not had chance to update this. This is the correct answer though, thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Do you want the data to be displayed in the Templars? In which case you'll need to add controls to the templates and add data binding expressions to them

**Edit** you could try find control in code behind then data bind directly to the controls in code behind

**yet another edit**. [this may help](http://forums.asp.net/t/1862868.aspx?Databind%20Linq%20Query%20results%20to%20a%20repeater)

Comment: Hi, yes I do. I've added `<p><%# Eval("Name") %></p>` to the <ItemTemplate> but still no results.

Comment: Did it work? If not put it into a server control, for example <asp:label id="label1" runat="server" text='<%# Eval("Name") %>' />